# Sequelize and query between tables

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have three models:

```
Entity
  - id
  ...


Event
  - id
  - metadata_field_id
  - entity_id
  - value (TEXT)

MetadataField
  - id
  - name (TEXT)
```

Having an array of pairs of `MetadataField.name`s and `Event.value`s, I want to build a query which would select the entities matching those pairs: should be a global `AND` and then for each event, `Event.value` should be the current value from the array and `Event.MetadataField.name` should be the current name.

I'm not sure how to build this using Sequelize (I'm not sure even how the query should look like).

What I've tried is:

```
const eventValues = [["some_name", "some_value"], ["another_name", "another_value"]]
if (eventValues.length) {                         
    queryObj.include = [{                         
        model: Event,             
        where: {
            [Op.and]: eventValues.map(c => ({     
                value:  {                         
                    [Op.like]: `%${c[1]}%`        
                }                                 
            }))                                   
        },                                        
        include: [{                               
            model: MetadataField, 
            [Op.and]: eventValues.map(c => ({     
                name:  {                          
                    [Op.like]: c[0]               
                }                                 
            }))                                   
        }]                                        
    }]                                            
}                                                 
return Entity.findAll(queryObj)
```

But this doesn't work, obviously, because it wants to select the `MetadataField`s names having *all* the provided names and same for values.

How should this be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not mandatory that you can only write where condition within include model only , but you can write that out outside of that also , but in that case all you need is to define table name also b/w `'$table_name.field_name$'` ,

So , Here you go :

```
const eventValues = [["some_name", "some_value"], ["another_name", "another_value"]]
if (eventValues.length) {                         
    queryObj.include = [{                         
        model: Event,                                        
        include: [{                               
            model: MetadataField
        }]                                        
    }],
    queryObj.where =   {
            [Op.or]: eventValues.map(c => ({     
                '$events.value$' :  {  // <---- Magic is here                   
                    [Op.like]: `%${c[1]}%`        
                } ,    
                '$metadata_fields.name$' :  {  // <---- Magic is here                       
                    [Op.like]: c[0]               
                }                            
            }))                                   
        }                                         
}                                                 
return Entity.findAll(queryObj)
```

> NOTE : You might have to change the table name as per yours , where I
>   wrote `// <---- Magic is here`